# Deploying an MVC3 application - Does MVC need to be installed on client PC or possible to just ship bins?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, deployment

As the title states. Our current method of deployment installs MVC1 onto the user's PC, but then brings over necessary MVC3 DLLs and drops them into the bin folder. I am wondering... if we're bringing the DLLs over, does MVC1 need to be installed at all? Any sort of routing, IIS configuration, etc. which might go on through installing MVC?

Comment: I am having an engineering guy fire up a VM for me right now -- I was just curious. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't need to install MVC1.  See here for instructions for "bin deployment": http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BINDeployingASPNETMVC3WithRazorToAWindowsServerWithoutMVCInstalled.aspx

Comment: Thanks! I told my boss this, but am going to work on getting my VM going now. If anything goes weird I'll post back!